# Plotting in a loop (with basemap and pyplot)....problems with pyplot.clf()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some weather data for a research project.  The plot consists of 18 timesteps.  I decided the best way to accomplish this was to make a new plot for each timestep, save it a file, and create a new plot for the next timestep (using a for loop).

For example:

```
map_init  #[Basemap Instance]
extra_shapes  #[Basemap.readshapefile object]

for i in range(timesteps):
    #plot the weather data for current timestep to current plot
    map_init.imshow(data[i])

    # extra_shapes are county boundaries.  Plot those as polygons
    pyplot.Polygon(map_init.extra_shapes[i])

    # Plot the state boundaries (in basemap)
    map_init.drawstates()

    # add a colorbar
    pyplot.colorbar()

    # Save the figure
    pyplot.savefig(filepath)

    #close figure and loop again (if necessary)
    pyplot.clf()
```

The problem lies with `pyplot.clf()`

The code works except for one thing.  Only the first plot comes out as expected.  Every subsequent plot is missing the `extra_shapes` (ie no county boundaries).  I do not understand the relation between presence of `pyplot.clf()` and the failure of `pyplot.Polygon()` ?

If removed, `extra_shapes` is plotted, but then every plot has multiple colorbars (depending on the value of `i`).  The only reason `pyplot.clf()` is there is to avoid having 18 colorbars in the final plot.  Is there a way to force one and only one colorbar per plot?

Comment: The logic behind the original loop was a rather hasty attempt to make completely separate plots of each timestep.

Originally, map_init was assigned inside the loop as well as extra_shapes.  extra_shapes is a rather large dataset (as it contains the boundaries for each county in the United States and related territories).  Assigning extra_shapes each iteration of the loop became very time costly (the same with map_init).  So moving those two assignments outside of the loop, and everything broke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making a new figure instead of using clf().

e.g.

```
for i in range(timesteps):
    fig = pyplot.figure()
    ...
    fig.savefig(filepath)
```

Alternatively (and faster) you could just update the data in your image object
(returned by imshow()).

e.g. something like (completely untested):

```
map_init  #[Basemap Instance]
extra_shapes  #[Basemap.readshapefile object]


#plot the weather data for current timestep to current plot
img = map_init.imshow(data[0])

# extra_shapes are county boundaries.  Plot those as polygons
plygn = pyplot.Polygon(map_init.extra_shapes[0])

# Plot the state boundaries (in basemap)
map_init.drawstates()

# add a colorbar
pyplot.colorbar()

for i in range(timestamps):
    img.set_data(data[i])
    plygn.set_xy(map_init.extra_shapes[i])
    pyplot.draw()
    pyplot.savefig(filepath)
```

However, there's a chance that that method might not play well with basemap.  I may also be misremembering the correct way to redraw the figure, but I'm fairly sure it's just plt.draw()...

Hope that helps a bit anyway

Edit: Just noticed that you're drawing your polygons inside of a loop, as well. Updated the second example to properly reflect that.

Comment: thank you very much for the help.
I couldn't get my original loop to work as expected (even with the suggestion from your first example).

However, the second example works like a charm.  It actually makes more sense than my original loop.  The img data is really the only thing changing between each timestep.  

ps. see edited question above