# Define Multiple Variables In While Loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, while-loop

I need to define multiple variables within a while loop to be called inside of the while loop in Python.

Code:

```
tau = 0

while tau < 10:

(tau)

   d_abrv = "d" % tau
   day = "day" % tau

d_abrv = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=tau)
day = d_abrv.strftime('%a %d-%b-%y')
image_date = d_abrv.strftime('%Y%m%d')

plt.savefig(homedir + "/out/_tmax_" + d_abrv + "_ne.png", dpi = 300)

tau = tau + 1

sys.exit()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Ideally, I need to define a variable that loops through number 0 through 10. After, I need to be able to use this defined variable throughout the script, including defining new variables with the variable, e.g., `tau=0`, change `day0` to `day=day+tau`

Comment: `(tau)`? What do you expect this to do?

Comment: I'm not quite sure... I found a python script that appeared to achieve what I am trying to do so, trying to hack my way through the code. Please forgive my obviously-limited knowledge of Python!

Comment: I guess you got an `IndentationError`?

Comment: Your indentation is off. Was that intended or a bad cut'n'paste?

Comment: I don't know what you expect to get from (tau), but also you're incrementing tau outside of the while loop, did the indenting get messed up when you copied/pasted ?

Comment: could you add a description of what isn't working?

Comment: Perhaps a bad cut/paste. In it's simplest form, I just want to define a variable that will loop through 0-10 and then be able to use that defined variable throughout my script, as well as combining with other variables.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong if you dont tell us what you're expecting and what's actually happening. In addition you should be aware that python is sensitive to indentation - if the posted code actually looks like your code the `tau = tau+1` is not within the loop (besides the `(tau)` would result in syntax error).

Comment: Johannes, just added a description to original question.

Comment: I think instead of
    d_abrv = "d" % tau
    day = "day" % tau
you want
    d_abrv = "d_%d" % tau
    day = "day_%d" % tau
this would result in strings "day_0" and so on. But that would just store the string "day_0" in the variable day, not create a new variable day_0...

Comment: you should be using a for loop instead of while loop since you tau is supposed to be changing one at time on each loop. Right now it's going to be an infinite loop.

Comment: Aaron Perry, could you edit the indentation in your question, people will just keep on commenting on that and I think we clarified that this isn't your problem. I tried to submit an edit but apparently adding blank spaces doesn't qualify as a valid edit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean, but would this suffice?

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta


for tau in range(0,10):
   d_abrv = "d" + str(tau)
   day = "day" +str(tau)
   d_abrv = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=tau))
   day = d_abrv.strftime('%a %d-%b-%y')
   image_date = d_abrv.strftime('%Y%m%d')
   plt.savefig(homedir + "/out/_tmax_" + d_abrv + "_ne.png", dpi = 300)

sys.exit()
```

although I must say I'm not sure what this means:

```
plt.savefig(homedir + "/out/_tmax_" + d_abrv + "_ne.png", dpi = 300)
```

Comment: you should change it to a for loop since you know how many times to loop.

Comment: @scrineym he's saving the plot into that directory with the provided quality (dpi). It's a `matplotlib` function [`savefig()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)

Comment: This is great, except that it's not processing any plots, except plot 9... It's skipping over the processing part with basemap, etc etc

Comment: @AaronPerry  I'm wondering are you doing your processing outside of the for loop ? If you are tau would stay at 9 because that was the last value it was assigned

Comment: How can I check to see if the processing is running outside of the for loop?

Comment: @AaronPerry looking around you might have to create a new figure at the start of the loop see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460707/plotting-in-a-loop-with-basemap-and-pyplot-problems-with-pyplot-clf , basically above d_abrv="d" place in the code where you define what plt is

Comment: you do not have to call plt.plot() inside the loop, I did it outside with my code example (see other answer) and it created 10 plots.
Also, I would like you to be aware that not the first two lines and the fourth line inside the loop are not being used anywhere. I believe you always overwrite the plot because you insert d_abrv into the filename string, which is a datetime object and not the time-string you want. that has been saved as the variable day in this example. Edit: Nevertheless, it would probably make sense to plot something different in each iteration...

Answer (score -1):

If I correctly understood your problem, you want to create a new variable in every iteration of the loop. I have done this successfully in the past by using exec(). I am still uncertain whether this is a pythonic thing to do, but it worked. Based on your previous comments, I would suggest the following code:

```
tau = 0
timeformat = "'%a %d-%b-%y'"
timeformat2 = "'%Y%m%d'"

while tau < 10:

  exec("d%d = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=tau)" % tau)
  exec("day%d = d%d.strftime(%s)" % (tau,tau,timeformat))
  exec("image_date = d%d.strftime(%s)" % (tau,timeformat2))

  exec("plt.savefig(homedir + '/out/_tmax_' + day%d + '_ne.png', dpi = 300)" % tau)

  tau = tau + 1

sys.exit()
```

I tested this code (on some dummy data i plotted) and I successfully get the plots saved with filenames "_tmax_Fri 09-Oct-15_ne.png" etc.

The rest of your code would have the variables day0, day1, etc. available for use.

Comment: It's certainly not „pythonic“ and definately not the way to go.  You need `exec()` to define the variables and `exec()` again to refer to them, so you are creating, compiling, and executing extra code instead of simply storing the values in a dictionary.  Or even simpler in a list.

Comment: did you apply correct indentation to the "tau = tau + 1" line? Because that would cause an infinite loop. I am still wondering if you use indentation correctly. Incorrect indentation could also have caused your problem that you mentioned in the other comment: if your plt.savefig(...) is not indented to be inside the loop, but outside, it would only be called once after the final iteration.